# Is it possible to split a single project into multiple overlapping SVNs?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Is the following possible??...

### checkout 'core'

CORE / INTERFACE / corefile
CORE / APP / corefile

### checkout 'plugin_1'

PLUGIN_1 / INTERFACE / PLUGIN_1 / pluginfile
PLUGIN_1 / APP / PLUGIN_1 / pluginfile

### checkout 'plugin_2'

PLUGIN_2 / INTERFACE / PLUGIN_2 / pluginfile
PLUGIN_2 / APP / PLUGIN_2 / pluginfile

### checkout 'core' + 'plugin_1' + 'plugin_2'

ALL / INTERFACE / corefile
ALL / INTERFACE / PLUGIN_1 / pluginfile
ALL / INTERFACE / PLUGIN_2 / pluginfile
ALL / APP / corefile
ALL / APP / PLUGIN_1 / pluginfile
ALL / APP / PLUGIN_2 / pluginfile

I see from the comments below that svn:externals is the answer, and I think I now have it working.

Comment: Could you edit your post so that the directory hierarchy is readable ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a matter of facts you can. You'd have to make those two different repositories and in the main (third) one just point to them with svn:externals. You could do that by editing properties of a folder to which you want to add a folder from different repository.

Comment: But be aware that neither commits nor branching will recurse into external directories -- http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can even have one "inside" another.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be a case for [svn:externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html)?